# What does John Lennon mean when he references Betty Rollin's legs on the Dick Cavett show

Tags: the-beatles, interview

This is an interview of John Lennon on the Dick Cavett show. He keeps mentioning Betty Rollin's legs as some kind of joke.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7kXCnKfdGOY

---

I'm just wondering whether anyone knew what this refers to.  Here's a clip of the exact moment
https://youtu.be/7kXCnKfdGOY?t=16m48s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Betty Rollin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betty_Rollin) was a reporter, & previously a classmate of Yoko Ono at the [Sarah Lawrence College](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarah_Lawrence_College).

The Lennon comments apparently refer to an insulting report she made about Yoko -

> when the couple recounts the story of how journalist Betty Rollin, a classmate of Ono’s at Sarah Lawrence College, wrote a hurtful story in which she compared the pregnant Ono to Ernest Borgnine after Ono congenially made her a home-cooked meal.

*Source:* - [The Dick Cavett Show - John & Yoko Collection](http://www.popmatters.com/review/dick-cavett-show-john-and-yoko/)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Rollin described Yoko in very unflattering terms - which was especially insulting given the supposed friendship between the Sarah Lawrence College classmates - in an aricle she published after visiting their home for an interview. John was commenting subtly about her not being so hot herself, without being very specific.

Comment: Welcome to the site & hope you stick around!  This is a good answer, but it is essentially a duplicate of Tetsujin's, above.

Answer (score -3):

I think it is actually a reference to Rollin's breast cancer. She had already had one breast removed before this interview and subsequently lost the other to the disease. Lennon was clever enough to not mention her breasts but men look at legs and breasts as a matter of course when sizing up a woman. (Unless we're talking that reality show guy who became resident of the White House, and we know how he sizes up the ladies). John could be very nasty and I reckon he was being as nasty as he could get away with being without plunging into being repulsive and vile.

Comment: to rebuff the nasty comment that john lennon was referring to rollin's breast cancer, as well as her personal attack on the man, and frankly on all men, note that the dick cavett interview was in 1971, whereas, Rollin was first diagnosed with breast cancer in 1975, and again in 1984, each time losing a breast to the disease.